# Network share incorrectly mounted with root as owner

Tags: networking, share

I've been mounting my network share with the following entry under crontab:

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.1/usbdrive /home/pi/usbdrive
```

Since yesterday I've been unable to write information to it because the owner is set as root and write permissions are set to owner only.
I've now tried to do this via fstab:

```
//192.168.1.1/usbdrive  /home/pi/usbdrive  cifs  iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Unfortunately, the directory is still being mounted under owner=root.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Sometimes the usb stick runs into an issue where I need to unplug it from my router. I was thinking that it might have caused some problem. However, I am able to access the share via my Windows machine, so it seems to be working correctly on the router's side.

I've deleted the /home/pi/usbdrive and started over, with reboots in the middle. Nothing worked.

Appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://superuser.com/a/320640) might help you. it says that you can mount a drive with certain rights using:

```
 mount -t deviceFileFormat -o umask=filePermissons,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID /device /mountpoint
```

Comment: Specifying GID and UID in the fstab parameters did the trick. I still wish that I knew what made it stop working. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness sake, here's the full line:

 //192.168.1.1/lexar  /home/pi/usbdrive  cifs  iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm  0  0